# Properties defined in the properties section of the POM are not seen in external ant build file

Tags: maven, properties, ant, pom.xml, build.xml

I'm using maven-antrun-plugin in my pom.xml with external ant file.
It's said in plugin's document:

> All of the properties available to Maven are also available in the
>   target configuration. However, you may want to call an external Ant
>   build script using the ant task. To avoid name conflicts, only a
>   subset of the properties are passed to the external Ant build. ***These
>   include all properties defined in the properties section of the POM.***
>   It also includes prefixed versions of some of the commonly used Maven
>   properties.

So here's my pom, where I define "test.prop" property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testant</groupId>
    <artifactId>testant</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <test.prop>TestPropValue</test.prop>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>optional</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-index-properties</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <!--<property name="test.prop" value="${test.prop}"/>-->
                                <ant antfile="build.xml">
                                    <target name="echo-prop"/>
                                </ant>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And just trying to echo this property in build.xml:

```
<project default="test">
    <target name="echo-prop">
        <echo>${test.prop}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

This is what I get:

```
echo-prop:
     [echo] ${test.prop}
```

So property is not resolved as it should, according to the doc.
And it works fine only in case if I uncomment line with explicit property declaration under "tasks" tag.
Could you please help me in understanding, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: My first question is: Why do you need the maven-antrun-plugin ? What is the purpose ? Usually I would say this is a build smell?

Comment: Well, this is my project's specific. We already have existing functionality implemented as a ant task and I need to reuse part of it and add my own code.

Comment: That does not help...

Comment: I'm not sure what info I can give more. For ant task to successfully work, I need to pass some properties. It downloads some files, parses them, takes some info, outputs results to other files, etc. The ant does it job well. The only issue here is that I need to explicitly pass properties to the task, but it should (according to doc) take properties from <properties> section of pom. But is doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a version for the antrun-plugin:

```html
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.8</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
     (...)
</plugin>
```

ant by default passes all properties of the parent to an underlying "ant"-call. Unless you define inheritAll=false, all properties are passed.

In this case, you should have a look at the effective pom. There a very ancient version of the antrun-plugin is defined. 
As soon as you switch to a recent one, the example code works.